# 4 parallel requests in JMeter

Tags: ajax, jmeter

I have 1 usual request and 3 additional requests which should be perform in parallel with the first one:

usual request:

`URL=.../search?folder_Id=${folder_id}`

Parallel requests:

```
URL=.../search?folder_Id=${folder_id}&facet=company
URL=.../search?folder_Id=${folder_id}&facet=date
URL=.../search?folder_Id=${folder_id}&facet=author
```

Could you please write helpfull information what is the best and easiest way to implement this in JMeter?
All 4 requests should be in parallel for 1 user! Is it possible to do with JMeter or not?

UPD. These requests should be placed into controller - they are only one small but important part of huge script, so I can't use them as Thread group due to script logic, only inside of controller!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is even a [Parallel Controller Feature Request](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53159) which isn't resolved for the moment.

As an option, JMeter provides [Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) which will will pause threads until specified number will be active. You may consider having separate thread group with 4 threads orchestrated by Synchronizing Timer to fire off concurrently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to make 4 requests in parallel inside a controller, not Thread group? I have several Thread groups and in each there are sections with several controllers for different search types and inside of several of these controllers I need to run such parallel requests. How should I do this?

Comment: Hi Nadezhda. It is possible to use Synchronizing Timer inside i.e. Simple or even Transaction Controller along with 4 requests but you need to make sure that your Virtual Users number is aliquot to what you set in Synchronizing Timer to avoid the situation with deadlocked threads.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
I have test plan with following structure for each Thres Group:
- login;

- loop controller with

-- search type1 (no parallel requests);

-- search type2

---request1.1

----request1.2 (parallel with request1.1)

----request1.3 (parallel with request1.1)

----request1.4 (parallel with request1.1)

-log out.

So, 1 user or Thread group - and the situation when 4 requests in controller should be send in parallel for 1 user/Thread group.

Comment: All 4 requests are different, not the same!